# .isDisplayed()--> never returns False why? in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

.isDisplayed()--> never returns False why? it always give No Such Element Exception though i am using try catch block.

```
      try {
        boolean status_second= Appointment_Booking_page.second_confirmation.isDisplayed();
        System.out.println("Current Second Appointment booking status-->" + status_second);
      } 
      catch (NoSuchElementException e) {

      }
```

Please suggest for same.

Comment: if No such element exception comes, then the object is not on the page or you are using wrong locator value. check your xpath or any locator you have used. Some times, the element is not loaded, you may need to wait for the element to be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions is correct, isDisplayed will display True for the all the element that are present , anything else will definitely go to NoSuchElementException. This is correct only for the element which are displayed in the UI , check with an element that is not displayed example Hidden Elements, or for that matter the element which is displayed only after scrolling, i believe in these scenarios it should display False.

Here is another question regarding same:

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1880

Answer (score 1):

Is displayed is not giving you false because even before that method is executed ,NoSuchElementException is occured.
isDisplayed is used in cases where element is present in DOM and you need to check whether it is displayed or not in the UI. It is never used to check whether an element is present in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It is not *True* that `.isDisplayed()` method never returns *False*.

In your case `.isDisplayed()` method is invoked through `Appointment_Booking_page.second_confirmation` which is your possible *Strategy* to locate an webelement. As the *Locator Strategy* you have adapted doesn't identifies the intended webelement uniquely so (even before `.isDisplayed()` is invoked) `NoSuchElementException` is thrown and your program terminates.

It is worth to mention, even if the webelement is present on the *Web Page* but not within the [*Viewport*](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp), `.isDisplayed()` method can still return *False*.

Answer (score 0):

isDisplayed() is the method used to verify presence of a web element within the webpage. The method is designed to result from a Boolean value with each success and failure. The method returns a “true” value if the specified web element is present on the web page and a “false” value if the web element is not present on the web page

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of confusion around why isDisplayed method not returns false instead it throws NoSuchElementException ; the problem is with the understanding of when to use isDisplayed method

1. isDisplayed throws NoSuchElementException because the element isn't present in the DOM; (try inspecting element using your locating strategy for which you are getting the above exception in the browser using firepath or any developer tool in browser and you will see that your locating strategy has found 0 match elements)

When to use isDisplayed?

.isDisplayed() exists to tell you whether the element, **which has already been located i.e. your element is present in the DOM**(try inspecting element and you should find match element),is visible on the page; i.e. whether its width and height are greater than zero, it
isn't hidden by CSS, etc.  If the element is present on the page, but has style="display:none;" then isDisplayed() will return false.

what is meant by above statement is although you have matching element but as the element got hidden by CSS thus you are getting false

Answer (score 0):

.isDisplayed() does returns False
Here is an practical example of it-:
goto google.com and find and hidden element which is present in dom but doesn't highlight on ui.
For eg -:

```
Boolean dispReturn = driver findElement(By.name("source")).isDisplayed());
System.out.println(dispReturn)
```

;